# Max thread number for one application?

Tags: android

I wanna know about max thread number for one application.

You know Thread.activeCount() returns the number of active Threads in the running Thread's group and its subgroups.

If I can know the max number of threads to create in current activity, I can limit active threads.

I am using thread for http connection and catching Http response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22):

There is no maximum enforced by code that I am aware of. That being said, even for network I/O, diminishing returns will set in fairly quickly, since the CPU speed of Android devices is fairly small, and RAM is fairly limited.

Please consider using `AsyncTask` instead of your own threads. This uses a thread pool set up by Android, and so it will use a pool size that the core Android team believes is effective for the platform.

Comment: AsyncTask is great, the only issue is that on some Android versions you cannot have two tasks running in parallel (the tasks are executed serially) but on other versions you can. Any fix for that, apart from rewriting AsyncTask from its source code?

Comment: @Tomasz: "Any fix for that, apart from rewriting AsyncTask from its source code?" -- use `executeOnExecutor()` on API Level 11+ to opt into the `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

Comment: Or use ThreadPoolExecutor for specialized tasks, there you have greater control.

Comment: Please, use coroutines now (this is 9 years later). AsyncTask is verbose or lacks flexibility and facilities of suspending functions of Kotlin.

Comment: Do not use AyscTask, I repeat Do not use AyscTask :D

Comment: Well, just as an update (9 years later), using Coroutines is the way to go for multi-threading in Android. Google just deprecated the AsyncTask API in favour of Coroutines.