# How many Worker Threads can be created at most?

Tags: android, worker-thread, android-cursorloader

In my tablet app I use many *Fragments* (of one class) next to eachother in one activity, and in this Fragment class I have:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(this.position, null, this);
}
```

and

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(...)
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, proj, null, null, "distance");
}
```

Each Fragment starts **a new worker thread** for a *CursorLoader*. How far does this scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hard limit. However, if you are concerned about the number of threads you are starting, use AsyncTask as its `doInBackground` method runs in a pool of background threads. More information

- [Max thread number for one application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138510/max-thread-number-for-one-application)
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: Where did it state that AsyncTask employs a pool of background threads?

Comment: @Pacerier under *Using AsyncTask* it says "To use it, you must subclass AsyncTask and implement the doInBackground() callback method, which runs in a pool of background threads."