# Android's Text-to-speech is restarting the method(), which shouldn't?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I just want to make a quiz-kind of application where questions are asked & shown.

I am using the Android's default Text to Speech engine, instead of mediaplayer(I have no choice except tts plz...) .I am initializing tts & using it in mainmethod("switchingLogic()").

**Now, My problem is : The sound of first question should be played on start of the activity.But tts is not playing that sound if I place my SWITCHINGLOGIC() in onCreate().So, I have Placed it in the onInit() of tts , Desired output is coming, but "when the screen is locked & Unlocked, it is starting from the first question again."**

Now, how can I make my app to start from there only if app goes background or phone is Locked automatically.

```
public void playQuestions(String sound) {
    tts.speak(sound, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}



public void switchingLogic() {
playQuestion(item.getSounds(1));
--------------------
--------------------
}
@Override
public void onInit(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (arg0 == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        Log.d("Yes", "SUCCESS");
        switchingLogic();
    }
}
```

Disastrous Situation Please help me, this is new issue & wanna submit the app in 10 hours...

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because android supports only one thread in foreground, so when you lock the screen and unlock, your application goes to background and the present state of your application will be lost... as you have used 
**`playQuestion(item.getSounds(1));`** 
It makes ur application to open again and start from 1st Question.

Comment: thanks for the early reply Pavan , You are correct(may be), But what about the sound not playing for the first time if I place the method containing tts engine in "onCreate()" & it is playing if I place it in the "onInit()" of TTS.This is my main concern...

Comment: @sai Have a look At this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138510/max-thread-number-for-one-application)