# How much processros and threads can I create?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, multiprocessing

Yesterday I was in a interview and  I should to give the answer for the question "How much processros and threads can I create in Android app?"
What is the true answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138510/max-thread-number-for-one-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically [there is no limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138510/max-thread-number-for-one-application) to how many threads you can create.

I should mention two things though (somewhat simplified):

1. You can ***not*** create a [*processor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_(computing)). Processor typically refers to hardware (CPU, core etc). You can however create *threads* or *processes*, which the processor runs. Note that *process* is more of a higher level OS-term, not entirely equivalent to *thread*.
2. Because of things like [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), the more threads you have per core, the slower your program will be. Generally, the optimal number of threads (for pure execution speed) is one per core. For example: 40 threads running on a 4-core processor will be slower than 4 threads on a 4-core processor. There are some important exceptions to this, e.g. networking.